# Formatting Time/Date from different time zones in Powershell

Tags: powershell, timezone

I need to convert UTC time/date output to Eastern Standard Time in ISO 8601 (or similar) format using Powershell for use in a DOS Batch file.

I have very little experience with Powershell, but have previously modified existing Powershell commands for various DOS batch files.  Powershell can easily output time/date from numerous time zones, but it's not clear if it can readily display that output in a numerical format.

In a DOS batch file, Powershell can be called to display UTC time in this format --

```
echo | powershell (get-date).ToUniversalTime().ToString('yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss')
```

I need to call upon other time zones, but the output is 'FullDateTimePattern' which is spelled out --

```
echo | Powershell [System.TimeZoneInfo]::ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId((Get-Date), 'Line Islands Standard Time')
```

I was hoping that the previous commands could (somehow) be merged together, or if one of the 'Get-Date -format' specifiers could be applied to the second code sample, or if an offset value could be applied to the UTC time/date output, or if there is some other easy code solution (or utility) that I could incorporate into a DOS batch file.

Comment: have a look at [datetime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime?view=netframework-4.8) as it looks like a thin wrapper around datetime. Skeet's post still applies on [datetime](https://blog.nodatime.org/2011/08/what-wrong-with-datetime-anyway.html) as far as I know so keep in that mind.

Comment: Just add part with `ToUniversalTime().ToString('yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss')` to the end of your second example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To convert the current UTC `[datetime]` instant to Eastern Standard Time with the specified format:

```
powershell.exe -c "[System.TimeZoneInfo]::ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId([datetime]::UtcNow, 'Eastern Standard Time').ToString('yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss')"
```

Note the following additional improvements:

- No need for `echo |`: When PowerShell is invoked with a command with (possibly implied) `-Command` / `-c`, it automatically exits after completing that command. (As an aside, `echo |` doesn't send just a *newline*, it sends the string `ECHO is on.`, followed by a newline; to send just a newline, you'd have to use `echo. |`
- Option `-c` (`-Command`) is used explicitly, not just to make the intent clearer, but also to ease potential later transition to PowerShell *Core*, where `-Command` is no longer the default (`-File` is).
- While your specific command would work without the enclosing double quotes (`"..."`), it's generally better to use them, so that commands that include `cmd.exe` metacharacter - e.g., `&` - don't break.

Comment: The OP said they wanted to convert from UTC to Eastern time.  `ToUniversalTime` shouldn't be used, as that converts from local time to UTC.  I'd recommend either using [the version of `ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId` that takes a `DateTime` and two strings](https://docs.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.timezoneinfo.converttimebysystemtimezoneid#System_TimeZoneInfo_ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId_System_DateTime_System_String_System_String_) with `"UTC"`, and `"Eastern Standard Time"`, or use [`ConvertTimeFromUtc`](https://docs.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.timezoneinfo.converttimefromutc).

Comment: Thanks, @MattJohnson, good pointers. I'm unclear on what the OP truly wants, so I've simplified the answer to show just one specific conversion.

Comment: @MattJohnson Could you provide code examples for `ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneID` and `ConvertTimeFromUTC` converting the current time from UTC (or Line Islands Standard Time) to Eastern Standard Time?   (If only for another possible solution to the question).

Answer (score 1):

Much thanks for the helpful the replies.  I noticed one can apply the documented Microsoft Get-Date format specifiers to time zones in this manner (which wasn't obvious, given my lack of Powershell experience).

Testing most of these options on the widest spread time zones can be helpful.

Dateline Standard Time [(UTC-12:00) International Date Line West]
Line Islands Standard Time [(UTC+14:00) Kiritimati Island]

***The following code was run on Saturday, June 01, 2019 1:01 PM Eastern Standard Time to convert to Line Islands Standard Time (UTC+14:00)***

ShortDatePattern: `Get-Date -format d` equivalent

```
Powershell.exe -c "[System.TimeZoneInfo]::ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId((Get-Date), 'Line Islands Standard Time').ToString('d')"
```

**6/2/2019**

LongDatePattern: `Get-Date -format D` equivalent

```
Powershell.exe -c "[System.TimeZoneInfo]::ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId((Get-Date), 'Line Islands Standard Time').ToString('D')"
```

**Sunday, June 02, 2019**

Full date and time (long date and short time): `Get-Date -format f` equivalent

```
Powershell.exe -c "[System.TimeZoneInfo]::ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId((Get-Date), 'Line Islands Standard Time').ToString('f')"
```

**Sunday, June 02, 2019 7:01 AM**

FullDateTimePattern (long date and long time): `Get-Date -format F` equivalent

```
Powershell.exe -c "[System.TimeZoneInfo]::ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId((Get-Date), 'Line Islands Standard Time').ToString('F')"
```

**Sunday, June 02, 2019 7:01:23 AM**

General (short date and short time): `Get-Date -format g` equivalent

```
Powershell.exe -c "[System.TimeZoneInfo]::ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId((Get-Date), 'Line Islands Standard Time').ToString('g')"
```

**6/2/2019 7:01 AM**

General (short date and long time): `Get-Date -format G` equivalent

```
Powershell.exe -c "[System.TimeZoneInfo]::ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId((Get-Date), 'Line Islands Standard Time').ToString('G')"
```

**6/2/2019 7:01:25 AM**

MonthDayPattern: `Get-Date -format m` or `Get-Date -format M` equivalent

```
Powershell.exe -c "[System.TimeZoneInfo]::ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId((Get-Date), 'Line Islands Standard Time').ToString('m')"
```

**June 2**

Round-trip date/time pattern: `Get-Date -format o` equivalent

```
Powershell.exe -c "[System.TimeZoneInfo]::ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId((Get-Date), 'Line Islands Standard Time').ToString('o')"
```

**2019-06-02T07:01:27.8492082**

RFC1123Pattern: `Get-Date -format r` or `Get-Date -format R` equivalent

```
Powershell.exe -c "[System.TimeZoneInfo]::ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId((Get-Date), 'Line Islands Standard Time').ToString('r')"
```

**Sun, 02 Jun 2019 07:01:28 GMT**

SortableDateTimePattern (based on ISO 8601) using local time: `Get-Date -format s` equivalent

```
Powershell.exe -c "[System.TimeZoneInfo]::ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId((Get-Date), 'Line Islands Standard Time').ToString('s')"
```

**2019-06-02T07:01:29**

ShortTimePattern: `Get-Date -format t` equivalent

```
Powershell.exe -c "[System.TimeZoneInfo]::ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId((Get-Date), 'Line Islands Standard Time').ToString('t')"
```

**7:01 AM**

LongTimePattern: `Get-Date -format T` equivalent

```
Powershell.exe -c "[System.TimeZoneInfo]::ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId((Get-Date), 'Line Islands Standard Time').ToString('T')"
```

**7:01:32 AM**

UniversalSortableDateTimePattern using the format for universal time display:  `Get-Date -format u` equivalent

```
Powershell.exe -c "[System.TimeZoneInfo]::ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId((Get-Date), 'Line Islands Standard Time').ToString('u')"
```

**2019-06-02 07:01:33Z**

Full date and time (long date and long time) using universal time: `Get-Date -format U` equivalent

***Applying this option to any time zone (other than UTC) seems to give a +4:00 offset (perhaps depending upon local time zone), which could be problematic.***

```
Powershell.exe -c "[System.TimeZoneInfo]::ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId((Get-Date), 'Line Islands Standard Time').ToString('U')"
```

**Sunday, June 02, 2019 11:01:34 AM**

YearMonthPattern: `Get-Date -format y` or `Get-Date -format Y` equivalent

```
Powershell.exe -c "[System.TimeZoneInfo]::ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId((Get-Date), 'Line Islands Standard Time').ToString('y')"
```

**June, 2019**